# Convert Bitmap data into the image tag format

Tags: asp.net, bitmapdata

i have function which will create the thumbnail image :

```
Image photo=System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myFile.InputStream);

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
graphic.DrawImage(photo, 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

The bmp image will be in bitmap format.
How do I convert it so I assign in image tag and display on a page?

Answer (score 1):

You can return byte array in following way.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
Byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
buffer = stream.ToArray();
return buffer;
```

and using generic handler you can show this data in image tag.

Answer (score 1):

I build a snippet from several ideas, this works perfectly:

```
 Bitmap original = new Bitmap(@"C:\path\img.jpg");
 Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
 Bitmap cropped = (Bitmap)original.Clone(srcRect, original.PixelFormat);
 byte[] imgbytes;    
 using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
 {
        cropped.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        imgbytes = stream.ToArray();
 }
 <img src="@String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(imgbytes))" />
```

Within the Rectangle the offset is (0,0) and crops 100x100 Pixels from the orignal.